# Is it proper to do all stuff in popup.js for a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making my first Chrome extension so I'm a little stranger to proper ways. This extension for save your Chrome tabs and then load them back. So it access to user's tabs, tab groups, local storage. I do all my process in popup.js. My background.js is empty. Is it proper? Should I move some parts to background? I don't know how I can do some stuff in background and than update the popup.html.

Comment: In short, if you don't listen to `chrome` API *events* then you don't need the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm What do you mean with listening to Chrome API events?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#events